# JQuery - How to set parent attribute based on child attribute?

Tags: jquery

I have the following table :

```
<tbody>
<tr data-id="#ID#">
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="ID">1</td>
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="PARTICIPANT">61</td>
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="ORDER_">1</td>
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="INVITEDBY">61</td>      
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="OPERATION">21</td>
</tr>
<tr data-id="#ID#">
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="ID">21</td>
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="PARTICIPANT">101</td>       
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="ORDER_">1</td>
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="INVITEDBY">61</td>      
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="OPERATION">21</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I would like to set the  attribute **data-id** based on the child attribute **headers**.

I wrote the following code :

```
var el = this.affectedElements[0];

// first part : not working
$(el).find("[headers='ID']").each(function(){
    $(this).parent().attr('data-id',$(this).data("id"));
});

// second part : works
$(el).find("tbody").sortable({
    items: 'tr'
  , containment: el
  , update: function(event,ui) { updateDisplaySeq(el); }
});
```

The second part of the code makes the rows sortable and it's working, while the first part doesn't work.

Can anyone help please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr").each(function(index, element){
    var parentId = $(element).find('.t-Report-cell[headers="ID"]').text();
    $(element).data("id", parentId);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tbody>
<tr data-id="">
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="ID">1</td>
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="PARTICIPANT">61</td>
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="ORDER_">1</td>
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="INVITEDBY">61</td>      
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="OPERATION">21</td>
</tr>
<tr data-id="">
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="ID">21</td>
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="PARTICIPANT">101</td>       
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="ORDER_">1</td>
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="INVITEDBY">61</td>      
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="OPERATION">21</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```